# How can I assign a 2D array variable to a big floating matrix in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parsing, matrix

I need to store and frequently use a couple of relatively big matrices (each 160 x 128, to be exact) in Swift. In order to initialize a constant 2D Double array to hold that matrix, I have written something like this: `let myMatrix = [[3.2, 5.8976, 5.2], [1e-4, 0.3, 8.56]]`. This 2 x 3 array is just an example. When you try to write a 160 x 128 floating point matrix, it takes lots of lines. I have typed this long expression using a MATLAB script that I have written just for that. However, when I copied and pasted the very long expression of this big matrix, XCode stops responding. It cannot handle such a big, lines of data in the "ViewController.swift" file. So, I need to find another way to store my matrices in an iPhone app. I have checked "XML", "plist" and "CSV" file formats to use. Unfortunately, non of those worked for me. I look for an easy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to StackOverflow. There are a few issues at play here, I'll try to address them all:

## There are no 2D arrays

*Technically*, Swift doesn't have 2D arrays (until you implement one, that is). What you're describing are nested arrays, which have slightly different characteristics:

1. There's no guarantee that such an array has equally-sized rows. The first could be 160 wide, the second could be empty.
2. It has worse performance characteristics, because it's an array of arrays, rather than one contiguous array containing all elements. That is, it's stored...

   - more like:

     [image: array of arrays]
   - than like:

     [image: contiguous storage]

## What a ViewController should do

It should control views. Storing a 160x128 matrix doesn't sound like "controlling a view" to me, and as such, is completely inappropriate for such code to be put there

## Compiling large expressions

Without type hints, the Swift type checker is left to infer the types in play in our code. For example, while `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]` might obviously look like an `Array<Array<Int>>`, it could actually be used to initialize a `ArraySlice<Set<Double>>`, if that's what the context asks for.

In Swift, literal expressions can have one of many types. The square bracket syntax used for Array can actually be used to initialize any type that conforms to `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` (such as `Set`, `ArraySlice`, or any such types you invented yourself). Similarly, integer literals can be used to initialize any type that conforms to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`, such as `Float`, `Double`, and every variant of `(U)Int(64|32|16|8)`. Taken together, an array literal has a *lot* of possible types it could be, which takes the type checker really long to evaluate.

You could help this along by fully specifying the type (e.g. giving a type hint on the variable: `let matrix: [[Double]] = [ ... ]`. But even still, this data is far too big to be appropriate to put in a Swift file.

## Using a serialization format

... is the right way to go. In this case, I would think CSV is probably the most appropriate (it's really good at storing square tabular data like this). You say that you 'checked "XML", "plist" and "CSV" file formats' (I don't know what "checked" means here) and that 'on of those worked for me' (didn't work for *you*? what do that mean, the code has some check `if (user == Serhat) dontWork()`?). That's the correct approach for a good solution. If you're stuck there, you should post a question that gives more detail on exactly what went wrong, so that others could actually help you.

Comment: Wow. I am quite impressed. What a detailed answer. Thank you. I asked such a non-specific, open ended question because I did not know what I do not know. I had to just jump to the problem. The problem that I try to solve does not require any graphics. It only requires some math. According to the result of my mathematical calculations on Swift, it will play different sound files. With your answer, I learned lots of things. Now, I know what I do not know. Also, I have more specific questions now: Is using [[Double]] arrays for mathematical operations efficient? Or, is there another recommendd...

Comment: ... way to implement linear algebra operations with big sizes? As a more specific question, I implemented the code given in this link: http://blog.alsedi.com/one-line-csv-parser-with-swift-the-power-of-swift/ However, when I run the code on my iPhone, a fatal error message appears. It says there are nil values. I checked the internet about this (this is what I meant by check), but I could not find any solution. I guess, it has a problem about line ending chars. Thanks again. I really appreciate your detailed answer.

Comment: Finally, here is the exact error message: "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file"

Comment: @SerhatSoyer Is `[[Double]]` sufficient? Probably. Depends on what you're doing. There are probably linear algebra libraries out there that have efficient implementations of the various data structures/algorithms you may need but, I haven't tried any of them, so I don't have any concrete recommendations.

Comment: @SerhatSoyer That "CSV parser" is really rudimentary. For example, consider a CSV file with the content: `a, "these should be , together", c`. That implementation doeesn't know how to handle quoted strings, where commas have their literal meaning, and not their meaning as delimiting symbols, so it would give the incorrect result of `["a", "these should be ", "'together", "c"]. It'll probably be enough for what you're trying to do, but I would recommend using an existing implementation, like SwiftCSV.

Comment: "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" Is a *really* common error message, with hundreds if not thousands of questions on here. It just means you said to the compiler "I'm absolutely sure this optional value is `nil`, unwrap it for me. I wouldn't even know what to do if it was `nil`, so just crash the program please". But the optional *was* nil, and so the program did exactly what you asked it to do (crash).